# My Javascript Timer on my scoreboard goes at -1 after it goes at 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

i seem to have found a small problem on my scoreboard. If i set it for example, to exactly 1 minute (1:00), it would do 1:0-1 then 0:59. I don't quite understand why it does that, Here's my code:

```
var minutes = 0;
var c = 0;
var secondes = 0;
var commence = setInterval(commencer, 1000);
clearInterval(commence);

function commencer(){  
    secondes -= 1;
    document.getElementById('temps').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + secondes;
        if (secondes < 10) {
            document.getElementById('temps').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + c + secondes;
        }    
        if (secondes <= 0) {
            secondes = 60;
            minutes = minutes - 1;
            if (minutes < 0) {
                clearInterval(commence);
                minutes = 0;
                secondes = 0;
                clique = 0;
            }
        }    
}
```

Comment: Because you subtract 1 from seconds before doing anything with it (defined initially as 0, which creates -1). First check your logic, then display values.

Comment: You subtracted 1 away from the seconds before performing whatever else and you displayed that

Comment: How does this even run? You `clearInterval()` immediately after you `setInterval()`

Comment: A better way of counting down is to only count down `seconds`, then show `Math.floor(seconds / 60)` as minutes and `seconds % 60` as seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's what you told it to do.

- You started with 1 minutes 0 seconds (actually you didn't, but let's assume your code is changed to match your question).
- Then you subtracted one second, to get 1 minutes -1 seconds
- You wrote this to the HTML
- *Then* you performed arithmetic to handle the underflow, to get 0 minutes 59 seconds
- One second later, repeat

Change the order around and it'll work more as you expected:

```js
// Changed minutes from 0 to 1
var minutes = 1;
var c = 0;
var secondes = 0;
var commence = setInterval(commencer, 1000);

// Removed "clearInterval" call that stops the
// whole thing from running

function commencer() {
    secondes -= 1;
    
    // This has moved up
    if (secondes <= 0) {
        secondes = 60;
        minutes = minutes - 1;
        if (minutes < 0) {
            clearInterval(commence);
            minutes = 0;
            secondes = 0;
            clique = 0;
        }
    }
    
    // This has moved down
    document.getElementById('temps').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + secondes;
    if (secondes < 10) {
       document.getElementById('temps').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + c + secondes;
    }    
}
```

```html
<span id="temps"></span>
```

Your new problem is that the underflow checker sets seconds to 60, so you end up with `0:60`. I doubt this is what you intended.

I would now change `if (secondes <= 0)` to `if (secondes < 0)` and change `secondes = 60` to `secondes = 59`, though I haven't verified that this is correct; I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: Which one should i start with?

Comment: @DavyDO: Work through your algorithm with pen and paper, observing the state of everything at each step.

Comment: Ok, i got it all figured out now, Thank you so much everyone!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code for 1 minute timer, it will also pad 0 while it counts down. just place the div id=clockdiv, add class for seconds and minutes and it should be displayed properly.

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
    var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    return {
        'total': t,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
    };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
    var clock = document.getElementById(id);
    var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
    var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

    function updateClock() {
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

        minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

        if (t.total <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timeinterval);
        }
    }

    updateClock();
    var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 60 * 1000);

initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```